# API call for "Check mail from other accounts > Check mail now"?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Is there an Gmail API call that corresponds to "Check mail from other accounts > Check mail now"?

Comment: Why do you need to use the API to do that? Could you add a bit more context to it?

Comment: By default, Gmail seems to check my POP3 account every 20-40 minutes. 90% of the time that's fine, but sometimes I'm expecting something, like a 2fa code, that I need immediately. Getting to the settings page is nearly impossible on mobile, so being able to create a button that would trigger it would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Gmail API nor Apps Script's GmailApp have a way to force to update the messages from the other accounts pulled with POP3.

There may be an easy way to update those accounts from the app. Asking how to do this may bring people that knows how to do so and may be able to help you (but that know nothing about Gmail API) :)

As a side note, if you don't find a way of doing it, you may [request Google to implement a refresh method in their Gmail API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191602&template=824107).

### References

- [Gmail API resource summary (Gmail API reference)](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest)
- [Class GmailApp (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app)
- [Getting started (Google Issue Tracker documentation)](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at:
https://www.danielslaughter.com/projects/gmail-pop3-checker-for-greasemonkey/

(I have no affiliation with this)

This adds a refresh button to the Gmail interface to force fetch your configured POP3 accounts.

Works on several browsers, like Chrome, Firefox and Edge.